# Call a function when two conditions are right using IF statement

Tags: javascript

I need to know how to look for two values in `if` statement.
I know about a method where the code will be executed when at least one value matches the specified number like in here:

```js
if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
  // code to be called
}
```

But the code above will be executed even if one value matches 0 and the other not. What's the way to check if both `x` and `y` are equal to 0?

I couldn't find the answer anywhere...

Comment: `x == 0 && y == 0`

Comment: you're using the OR operator || , you need to use the AND operator && , so x==0 && y == 0

Comment: Is it really yhis simple?

Comment: Yes i know how binary works, but so i won't have to ask anymore about that.. are there any other ways to check values in IF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the AND operator instead of the OR operator, that is

```
if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
// code to be called
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use AND, which is &&